# JNI can't release memory

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jvm, java-native-interface

This is JNI's C++ code:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_cn_rilled_encoder_JNIEncoder_encodeEncryptBuff(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject obj,
        jbyteArray ucInBuffer,
        jintArray unInbufferLen,
        jintArray unOutbufferLen) {

    jbyte *bytes;
    bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(ucInBuffer, 0);
    int chars_len = env->GetArrayLength(ucInBuffer);
    // chars = new unsigned char[chars_len];
    unsigned char* chars = (unsigned char *) malloc(chars_len);
    memset(chars,0,chars_len);
    memcpy(chars, bytes, chars_len);
    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(ucInBuffer, bytes, 0);

    int inLength = env->GetArrayLength(unInbufferLen);
    int* inArray = env->GetIntArrayElements(unInbufferLen,0);

    int outLength = env->GetArrayLength(unOutbufferLen);
    int* outArray = env->GetIntArrayElements(unOutbufferLen,0);

    unsigned char* encryptBuff = WCCEncode_Encrypt_Buff(chars, (unsigned int*)inArray, (unsigned int*)outArray);

    jbyteArray bArray=env->NewByteArray(*outArray);

    env->SetByteArrayRegion(bArray, 0, *outArray, (jbyte *)encryptBuff);
    //env->DeleteLocalRef(bArray);
    //env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(bArray, (jbyte *)encryptBuff, 0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(unInbufferLen, inArray, NULL);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(unOutbufferLen, outArray, NULL);
    free(chars);

    return bArray;
}
```

This is JNI's Java code:

```java
public class JNIEncoder {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    public static native byte[] encodeEncryptBuff(byte[] ucInBuffer, int[] unInbufferLen, int[] unOutbufferLen);

}
```

Call it in java thread:

```java
byte[] result = JNIEncoder.encodeEncryptBuff(content, new int[]{content.length}, outLength);
```

memory usage:

> [image: memory usage]

memeory usage after freeing chars:

> [image]

Comment: Based on what you've shown us, you're never freeing `chars`. Why are you even using `new unsigned char[]` instead of something like `std::vector<unsigned char>` which will get released automatically when it falls out of scope? `GetByteArrayElements` might even have created a copy for you already, but you never check for that. And I don't understand why the length parameters to your `encodeEncryptBuff` function are themselves arrays(?).

Comment: I guess you will have to write a separate function in your JNI to free up memory after your operation, Unlike Java , C++ will not free up memory.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, this is my first time using JNI, and my code doesn't look good.I have changed the code, memory usage is much better than brefore, but it still seems to be a problem.Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with `delete encryptBuff`.

#### New Code

```
...
unsigned char* chars = (unsigned char *) malloc(chars_len);
...
free(chars);
delete encryptBuff;

return bArray;
```

New memory usage:

> [image: new memory usage]